# How to publish Grunt-assembled web site to the root of Azure Web App using Kudu?

Tags: gruntjs, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, kudu

I have a web site assembled (is it the right term?) by Grunt. It has the following structure:

```
/
  src/ (input)
    doc/
    images/
    js/
    scss/
    Web.config
  external/
  node_modules/
  dist/ (output)
    css/
    fonts/
    images/
    js/
  gruntfile.js
  package.json
```

To publish it to an Azure Web App using Continuous Deployment and Kudu I added [the following files](https://gist.github.com/abatishchev/f6a58e30d76d1953e8fe):

```
.deployment
deploy.cmd
```

I can upload the web site to /src and deploy it to /dist like this:

```
Directory of D:\home\site\wwwroot

06/30/2015  01:50 AM    <DIR>          .
06/30/2015  01:50 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/30/2015  02:21 AM                30 .deployment
06/30/2015  02:21 AM             3,679 deploy.cmd
06/30/2015  12:44 AM    <DIR>          dist
06/30/2015  12:40 AM    <DIR>          external
06/30/2015  02:21 AM             5,697 gruntfile.js
06/30/2015  12:43 AM    <DIR>          node_modules
06/30/2015  02:21 AM             1,173 package.json
06/30/2015  12:40 AM    <DIR>          src
```

But when I specify the root as the destination I'm getting [an error](https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduSync/blob/master/lib/FileUtils.ts#L17):

> Source and destination directories cannot be sub-directories of each other

What is the right approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Changing answer based on discussion

Try using Virtual Directories: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

All sites have `site\wwwroot` point to the `/` virtual directory by default. If you want `\dist` to be your root then change the virtual directory entry to have `site\wwwroot\dist` as the physical path and `/` as the virtual directory.

[image]

<strike>You can configure you web.config to specify any script to be your startup script with the following config:</strike>

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="/src/index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Do you mean `path="/dist"`? If I do this way then I'm getting an error 500.1002 at /dist and Azure Web Apps Welcome Page at / (root).

Comment: The later (welcome page) I'm getting always, either way.

Comment: @abatishchev Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do here. I assumed you have a node project that you want to deploy to azure websites, with nothing special other than your node app's main entrypoint file is located in the dist folder rather than in the root folder. 

Is that not the case?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. And added [node.js] by mistake. I have a static html web site assembled by Grunt. I want to publish it to the root while grunt reads it from /src and outputs to /dist.

Comment: After I run  deploy.cmd the site is in /dist. So when I go to /dist everything works. But I want to go to / instead. Without leveraging url rewrite, etc If possible.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case try using Virtual Directories. Not 100% sure if that'll solve your problem but give it a shot. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Not exactly I was looking for (I thought to learn more about Kudu scripting) but this is excellent and elegant workaround. Thanks man!